# Youtube - How to get all videos from youtube trands page using PHP

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-api

I'm using youtube API to fetch the videos of a trend page. But I have found that google youtube API services only available for few specific country or region. But if I want to get the list of all videos of the country Egypt or Saudi Arabia?

http://www.youtube.com/trendsdashboard#loc0=egy&feed=views

Please advice..

Answer (score 0):

In order to get trending YouTube videos for a given region, you can make a GET request such as `[http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/standardfeeds/regionID/feedID?v=2][1]` where regionID is the country region as specified in this [chart](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/reference#Region_specific_feeds). It looks like Egypt and Saudi Arabia are currently not supported by this API.

Comment: Thanks. Any other alternatives can you suggest?